# How to get total number of open HTTP connections on a server?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, .net-4.0

I would like to get the total number of open HTTP (TCP port 80) connections that Windows is receiving at a given point in time.

Is there any way in .NET to obtain this?

Do I need to somehow query [IPGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactivetcpconnections.aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me:

```
var properties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
var httpConnections = (from connection in properties.GetActiveTcpConnections()
                       where connection.LocalEndPoint.Port == 80
                       select connection);
```